# Laravel Blade @yield is not displaying the @section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have text that is displayed in two spots (one for desktops and one for mobile). So instead of having to place the text in two spots each time, I thought that I could just make a section and display the text in each spot using `@yield`. I am getting no errors, but the content isn't getting written out to the dom as I was expecting it to.

Here is the blade template:

```
<nav class="blue">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-side-nav">
                @yield('navbar-dropdown')
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<ul id="nav-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    @yield('navbar-dropdown')
</ul>

{{-- List of items to place in the ul's --}}
@section('navbar-dropdown')
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Create Project</a></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Manage Projects</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="{{ url('auth/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Help</a></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Report a Problem</a></li>
@endsection
```

Am I misunderstanding how this works, or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@yield` only works when extending a layout.

You would be much better off putting the contents of your `narbar-dropdown` section in another file and then using include.

E.g. create a file at `resources/views/partials/navbar-dropdown.blade.php` and add:

```
<li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Create Project</a></li>
<li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Manage Projects</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
<li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="{{ url('auth/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Help</a></li>
<li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Report a Problem</a></li>
```

and then in your layouts file you would change:

```
@yield('navbar-dropdown')
```

to

```
@include('partials/navbar-dropdown')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That works! I also didn't know you could use `/` as separators I have always used `.` separators. Thanks!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Glad I could help! Yeah, you can use either :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't extend the layout. When you use `@yield` and `@section` you need to define the `@yield` in your layout that you want to extend.

This is your template file (called `Laravel/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`):

```
<html>
<nav class="blue">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-side-nav">
                @yield('navbar-dropdown')
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<ul id="nav-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    @yield('navbar-dropdown')
</ul>
</html>
```

And this is your file that will extend the template:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('navbar-dropdown')
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Create Project</a></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Manage Projects</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="{{ url('auth/logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Help</a></li>
    <li><a class="blue-text waves-effect" href="#!">Report a Problem</a></li>
@endsection
```

Hope this works!

Comment: No, I didn't extend the layout. It is in a nav layout which is included in another layout.